# Using typed datasets' connection string for client application

Tags: vb.net

I have set the connection string of my dataset(typed) as

```
Data Source=MyHomeServer\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbTestSharing;Integrated Security=True
```

This is going to be a client side application.  I need to change the machinename in the connection string so it could connect with server.
I do not know how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better make the connection string programatically...but if you want to change yours connection string, try this:

```
yourConnectionString = yourConnectionString.Replace("MyHomeServer", "<New Server>")
```

Where .Replace() it's a method of System.String.